# Mute SMS audio notification

Tags: notifications, sms, audio, mi-a1, macrodroid

My phone is kept always on vibrate mode. When the screen is on and I get an SMS I can see the pop up notification and that's fine. Problem is when the screen is off - SMS sender name is read out aloud " Message from [sender name]" preceded by two long vibrations

I find this highly annoying sometimes and found no setting to mute this ( to replicate screen on behavior). I don't  want to activate DND mode because I want to know that I have a text message waiting to be read via  vibrate buzz

Surprised to see that no one complains of this on the net so obviously no solution ( Imagine your phone is on vibrate in a meeting but your phone announces to the world message from AXAIRNF or some embarrassing contact name) I tried automation, some Xposed / Magisk modules but none worked

**Edit** These additional attempts didn't help

1. Switching off the notification of SMS app
2. Trying alternate apps such as Textra etc
3. Putting the device on low ringer / notification volume when screen is off
4. Suspecting Text-to-Speech to be the culprit, killed that service when screen is off - no luck

**Any solutions <sup>#</sup> including rooted means?**

Mia1 stock 8.1 rooted with Magisk and Xposed (had same problem on 8.0 too). [Stock Messaging app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging)

---

<sup>#</sup> If you want to suggest automating, please stick to MacroDroid (don't want to add another automation app just for this). Gravity Box doesn't help. If your solution involves an alternate messaging app, it should be good at blocking spam SMS / be able to control reading of sender name(Textra already tried)

Comment: Is this a Xiaomi-specific thing? None of my phones have ever done this.

Comment: @DanHulme Possibly as I don't have any other device to check. Also probably the reason, it's not on net. Search on Xiaomi forums didn't help

Comment: @DanHulme : You could be right, don't recall having this problem when I was on a custom AOSP ROM for a short while... Sigh... That much more difficult to get a solution

Comment: Have you checked [Accessibility --> Talkback --> settings --> Speak Caller ID](http://en.miui.com/thread-14777-1-1.html)? [OnePlus seems to have that as well](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/how-to-disable-caller-id-voice-announcement.259663/). But there it was Sound About, which apparently has such a setting in its "Alert Behavior" section (settings).

Comment: @izzy Good  google-fu, thanks but no such setting neither that app :-)

Comment: I have similar option on my Motorola device. It is Talk to me  under Moto voice. Using this setting device will read loud calls and texts when you are in particular location or in driving mode.

Comment: @RahulGopi Thanks. Ya, I know since I had Moto device but no such feature :(

Comment: Textra is a good messaging app which works well for both blocking and silencing certain contacts. I don't have a Xiaomi device at my end so there is not much I can help with. :(

Comment: @Firelord : Thanks for responding. I had used Textra earlier and yes it blocks well. Here the issue is that IDK who will send SMS when the screen is off. It could be a contact, non contact or those spammy ones or those non spam but with those long makes like banks, Airtel etc. You would be getting similar. All those sender names are read out. The issue I feel is not the messaging app but tts overriding the settings and reading out (name). To test this theory, I have just used Xposed edge to kill Google tts when screen is off//

Comment: And it didn't work. For anyone reading the question, I had to do what I didn't want - keeping the volume really low so that it is not read out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It had nothing to do with the device  settings (but OS bug )

It was a macro misbehaving and reading out for *any* contact rather than chosen contacts (since the device is always on vibrate wanted audio alert for text messages from chosen few).I never suspected this since a similar macro for incoming calls was working fine

**Edit:** Shared logs with the developer who confirmed that it is an **OS bug**

> My code in simple terms does a look up on the number in your contacts database and then when it matches it requests the ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME....your device OS has some kind of weird issue where it doesn't return a sensible name.

and hence it was getting triggered universally for any contact

Comment: Stupid of me not to figure this earlier and waste time (mine and other's). Interestingly this macro works fine on Marshmallow so something has changed

Comment: +1. How did you find out it was a macro to begin with?

Comment: @Firelord: Thanks. Pure chance. Was going through Macrodroid system log for something else and saw this activated, when they're was no reason. Something had changed I think in the way SMS are detected because same version of MD on MM works fine

Answer (score 1):

Some phones have a drive mode where the notifications are spoken. You might have a shortcut button from the pull down settings or go into the talkback settings and it should be near the bottom. 
If not a drive mode then go into talk back settings , tap verbosity, then unselect speak when screen is off.
See if that is the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have drive mode on my phone. All talk back settings are disabled and there isn't verbosity option any way